# Git on mac, how to view files currently in GIT?

Tags: git

I setup a file extension to be ignored, how can I tell if it was added to git?

I use git add -A to bulk add files.

btw, what popular GUI tools are used for diff's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git status` before you commit everything (as in just after you `git add`) will show you if your files with the extension you want ignored have been added.

I personally prefer to just use `git diff` but that's not a GUI. People seem to like Git-K.
If I'm reviewing code, I love Github's diff tools. Allows me to look at differences between entire branches and comment on specific lines of code.